# MS-SQL: unique constraint case-insensitive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I add a case-insensitive constraint without altering the column collation?

I've tried

```
CONSTRAINT [AK_User_Username_UserType] UNIQUE (LOWER([Username]) [UserType])
```

and

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [AK_User_Username_UserType] UNIQUE (LOWER([Username]) [UserType])
```

But it won't compile...

Do I need to add a computed column to achieve this??

Comment: yes, you need computed column . SQLServer doesn't support function based indexes.

Comment: What is the current column collation? I assume it must be CS? Why don't you want to change it to CI if you are not allowing any values to exist that differ only by case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes a computed column would achieve this for you. Or you could create an trigger that will fire on insert or updates. [Here is link to a question like yours on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637030/lowercase-constraint-sql-server)